# Calling Oracle Associative Array from UPDATE subquery gives PLS-00201 error

Tags: oracle, sql-update, associative-array

I am trying to lookup values from an associative array to update a table, but am getting error. Here is a bare minimum code to demonstrate the issue (my actual query is much more complex).

Am I missing something, or if this is an Oracle limitation is there a way around it?

```
CREATE TABLE t_employee AS SELECT cast('john' as varchar2(30)) emp_name, CAST (NULL AS NUMBER (5)) emp_id FROM DUAL;
DECLARE
    TYPE emp_typ IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
    emp_lookup   emp_typ;
BEGIN
    emp_lookup ('john') := 1234;
    UPDATE t_employee e
       SET emp_id = (SELECT emp_lookup (e.emp_name) FROM DUAL);
END;
/

--DROP TABLE t_employee;
```

**> PLS-00201: identifier 'E.EMP_NAME' must be declared**

and when I change the update to a simpler construct:

```
UPDATE t_employee SET emp_id = emp_lookup (t_employee.emp_name);
```

I get this weirdness: **PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type**

Same with SELECT. It seems to me that we cannot use associative arrays directly in SQL statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An associative array collection is a PL/SQL only data type; it cannot be used in SQL statements.

From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-8060F01F-B53B-48D4-9239-7EA8461C2170):

> ##### Table 5-1 PL/SQL: Collection Types
>
> | Collection Type | Number of Elements | Index Type | Dense or Sparse | Uninitialized Status | Where Defined | Can Be ADT Attribute Data Type |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Associative array (or index-by table) | Unspecified | String or PLS_INTEGER | Either | Empty | In PL/SQL block or package | No |
> | VARRAY (variable-size array) | Specified | Integer | Always dense | Null | In PL/SQL block or package or at schema level | Only if defined at schema level |
> | Nested table | Unspecified | Integer | Starts dense, can become sparse | Null | In PL/SQL block or package or at schema level | Only if defined at schema level |

...

> An **associative array** (formerly called **PL/SQL table** or **index-by table**) is a set of key-value pairs.

...

> Unlike a database table, an associative array:
>
> - Does not need disk space or network operations
> - Cannot be manipulated with DML statements

---

`VARRAY` and nested table collections can be used in SQL statements.

Comment: Thanks MT0 - that;'s what I was trying to find in the documentation, somehow it slipped me. Arrgh what a waste of a morning trying to get this to work!